# How to make a result datacontrol between a webservice and ejb datacontrol in ADF?

Tags: web-services, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I need to create a table using the result of a webservice call and a table from another database, how do I do that in ADF?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to aggregate two sources of information is to write use ADF Business Components:

1. Create a SQL-based View Object for the database table.
2. Override ViewObjectImpl.executeQueryForCollection() and programatically call your Webservice from this point.  You iterate over web service return and for each result you do:

   Row row = this.createRow();
   this.insertRow(row);
   row.setAttribute("..", "...");
   ......

Then, from Datasource point of view, you use your view object as a any normal view object.

You can also aggregate your logic (both db call and web service call) in a custom method of application module. The method executes the VO which returns all the records, then iterates over existing records in VO, grabs the IDs and calls the web service. After web service returns, you can add the row coming from the web service to your db-based vo.

Your VO, when showed in UI, will contain both records from DB and Webservice, altogether.

Comment: How do I get the database results in this class to implement it on this method after I called the webservice to finally make the rows? Thanks

Comment: Your view object takes care of that automatically, when calling super.executeQueryForCollection()

Comment: Yes but I need to use an ID from the table of the database to use it as a parameter to the webservice call, How do I get in the class the record from the database?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a model layer component that merges the two sources of data together.
This can be an ADF BC ViewObjects, but it can also be a simple Java class that access your WebService and the database, merge the data and expose a collection with getters and setters.
Then you can expose that Java class as a data control and drag it onto the page as a table.

Comment: I should create a jdbc connection inside the class or there is a way to get the resulting dataset from the database datacontrol in order to make the join with the results from the webservice? Thanks

Comment: It's your choice in terms of how to access the DB - JDBC, JPA or ADF BC are all possibilities.